# Parent thread join(): Blocks Until Children Finish?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread

I have a C++ class that does some multi-threading.  Consider the pseudo-code below:

```
void MyClass::Open() {
  loop_flag =  true;
  // create consumer_thread (infinite loop)
  // create producer_thread (infinite loop)
}
void MyClass::Close() {
  loop_flag = false;
  // join producer_thread
  // join consumer_thread
}
MyClass::~MyClass() {
  Close();
  // do other stuff here
}
```

Note that consumer_thread, producer_thread, and their associated functions are all encapsulated in MyClass.  The caller has no clue that their calls are multi-threaded and what's going on in the background.

Now, the class is part of a larger program.  The program has some initial multi-threading to handle configuration of the system since there's a ton of stuff happening at once.

Like this (pseudo-code):

```
int main() {
  // create config_thread1 (unrelated to MyClass)
  // create thread for MyClass::Open()
  // ...
  // join all spawned configuration threads
}
```

So my question is, when I call join() for the thread linked to MyClass::Open() (i.e., the configuration thread spawned in main()), what happens?  Does it join() immediately (since the MyClass::Open() function just returns after creation of producer_thread and consumer_thread) or does it wait for producer_thread and consumer_thread to finish (and therefore hangs my program).

Thanks in advance for the help.  In terms of implementation details, I'm using Boost threads on a Linux box.

Edited to add this diagram:

```
 main()
 |
 |
 |
 |--->configuration_thread (that runs MyClass::Open())
   |
   |
   |----> producer_thread
   |----> consumer_thread
```

If I call join() on configuration_thread(), does it wait until producer_thread() and consumer_thread() are finished or does it return immediately (and producer_thread() and consumer_thread() continue to run)?

Comment: 'join' waits until the thread finishes. Hence you need an indicator for the thread and all sub-threads to stop.

Comment: I understand this, but when does the thread for MyClass::Open() finish?  When the function returns or when the two spawned threads are finished?

My goal is to have the producer_thread and consumer_thread run even after the MyClass::Open() thread is joined (if that makes sense).

Comment: `Open()` will return immediately, after creating the threads. The threads will keep running.

Comment: Right, I get that part.  But when I call join() on a thread that runs Open(), do the producer_thread and consumer_thread() continue to run?

Comment: Yes they keep on running, until their functions return or the program ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (non detached) thread will be joignable, even after having returned from the function it was set to run, until it has been joined.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void foo(){
    std::cout << "helper: I'm done\n";
}

 int main(){

    cout << "starting helper...\n";
    thread helper(foo);

    this::thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

     cout << "helper still joignable?..." << (helper.joignable()?"yes!":"no...:(") << "\n";

    helper.join();
    cout << "helper joined!";

    cout << "helper still joignable?..." << (helper.joignable()?"really?":"not anymore!") << "\n";

    cout << "done!\n";

}
```

Output:

```
starting helper...
helper: I'm done
still joinable?...yes!
helper joined!
still joinable?...not anymore!
done!
```

As for how much time the `join` method takes, I don't think this is specified, but surely it doesn't't have to wait for all the other threads to finish, or it would mean that only *one* thread would be able to join all the others.

From §30.3.5:

> void Join();
>
> *Requires:* `joinable()` is `true`
>
> *Effects:* Blocks until the thread represented by `*this` had completed.
>
> *Synchronization:* The completion of the thread represented by `*this` synchronises with the corresponding successful `join()` return. [*Note:* Operations on `*this` are not synchronised. * -- end note*]
>
> [...]